# How to prevent REST API parameter alterations

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

I am building a REST API to expose all todo lists saved by a particular user. User authentication happens using OAuth2 protocol. I have an API GW that authorize access to this API
based on the access tokens. The API has an input parameter for user. All todo lists saved by the user specified through this parameter is returned by the API

Lets say user1 gets an access token after successful authentication. He uses that token to call this API, but sets the 'user' parameter to user2. Since the API GW gives access to
the API (as there is a valid access token), the request passes to the service which returns all todo lists of user2.

How does one prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you would want to store the `access_token` and the `user_id` together as a 1:1 relationship in somewhere like a SQL database. After that, you would be able to check the ownership of an `access_token` in your API.

Besides, if you're using [JWT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.2) format for `access_token`s, you may store the `user_id` in the token's claims instead of storing in a database.

Comment: thanks for the answer. How do you generalize this to any other API parameter? Embed them in the access token?

Comment: @simonjohnson I would say it depends on what you're building. First let's be clear that the authorization process involves two parts, which could results in two different identities: the authorization subject and the resource owner. The `user_id` as described in the linked JWT spec above stands for the authorization subject. You may either reuse the access_token owner's identity or add an extra parameter to the API to identify the resource owner.